# How can I fix this program? ( regarding % )

Tags: java

here's my program, now the result for 26% 6 should be 2. But my program gives me 20, 14, 8 and 2. How can I fix this? I'm a beginner, so please say something that I would understand!

```
public class Modulus {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int A, B;

        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        A = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter second number:");
        B = scan.nextInt();

        int C = A;

        while (C >= B) {
            C = C - B;
            System.out.println("The remainder is: " + C);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `%` perator ?

Comment: If you are talking about modulus: 26 % 2 should be 0. Am I missing something?

Comment: You application works just fine, and the remainder should be `0` not `2`.

Comment: 26 % 2 should be 0. % return the remaining of the division of 26 with 2.

Comment: I meant 26% 6... I shouldn't use %, I should write a program that does that. without using %...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the `System.out.println` outside the `while` loop..otherwise, it will print each time it subtracts the value of B from C

```
       while (C>= B)
       {
           C= C-B;
           System.out.println("The remainder is: " + C ) ;  // printing each time
       }
```

to

```
       while (C>= B)
       {
           C= C-B; 
       }
       System.out.println("The remainder is: " + C ) ;
```

Comment: oh my god. you wouldn't believe me, but I spent about 20 minutes re-writing, using different variables, etc...and that's my problem???WOW I will never pass this course :(( Thanks tho...I really need to pay more attention to little things

Comment: @YeamFox well, it takes some getting used to, but once that's done - its a piece of cake..

Answer (score 1):

You print inside the body of the loop. I think you need to print only once, when the loop completes.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you know you can use the `%` operator directly? E.g., `System.out.println("The remainder is: " + (A % B));`.

The error with your loop is that your print statement is within the loop; it should be after the end, printing only once the subtraction is finished.

P.S. Consider adding some special handling for negative or zero numbers, or your program could loop for a long time in that case...

Answer (score 0):

Put like this

```
           while (C>= B)
       {
           C= C-B;


       }
   System.out.println("The remainder is: " +  (A % B) ) ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this (eliminating the `C` variable, renaming the variables using the *Java Naming Conventions* and closing the `scan` instance):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Modulus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int operand1, operand2;
        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        operand1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter second number:");
        operand2 = scan.nextInt();
        while (operand1 >= operand2) {
            operand1 = operand1 - operand2;
        }
        System.out.println("The remainder is: " + operand1);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```